# Batch process to delete rows from a SQL Server table

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, wcf

I'm developing a WCF RESTful service with C#, .NET Framework 4.0 and SQL Server.

I have to do some maintenance every hour on database. I have to delete some rows from a table and update another one:

A user can post three quotes of the day each 24 hours. I have to delete each quote of the day older than 24 hours. And I have to update User table with the number of quote of the day he has.

My problem is that I don't know how to do it. I think I need a batch process that runs every hour and make this maintenance but I'm not sure if I can add this batch process to database or I have to add it to WCF RESTful service or I have to implement a program to do it.

How can I do it? I have to delete some rows from a table and update another one.

I think the SQL Server database and the WCF RESTful service will be hosted on Amazon.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways in which you could choose to do this. Two options that spring to my mind are :-

1. Create a SQL Server Job - that calls a procedure that will do the needful - and schedule this job to run every hour
2. Create a Windows Service - that periodically - in your case hourly - does the needful.

Since the logic is relatively straightforward, i would prefer the SQL Server Job. 
If you expect the logic to become more complicated over a period of time and would prefer not to deal with long SQL procedures, then the Windows Service option could be considered.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the Sql Server, try to create a Job that to delete and update de Rows that you need.
**A Sql Server Job can run whatever you need.**
You can schedule when it will be executed. 
To create a Sql Server job just execute the sql server management, connecto to the sql server and go to Sql Server Agent.

Create a job, then create the steps of the job and program it.
**How to create a Sql Server Job**
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190268.aspx
If you can't acces to the sql server agent to create a job, problably you should **program it in your service**  or **create a batch file using sqlcmd.**

```
sqlcmd -S myServer\instanceName -i C:\myScript.sql
```

then schedule it with the Windows Task Scheduler.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766428.aspx